# it is possible to add <data-*> values like classes?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there way to write data attributes in class-like form? I mean like this:

```
<div data-el="asset assets.asset">Some div</div>
```

And I want to use it like classes in selector, I need to find this element as "[data-el='asset']" and also as "[data-el='assets.asset']".

Maybe there is similar way to do so. Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the attribute selectors available:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

What you want to use is this:

```
[data-el~="assets.asset"]
```

That will find "assets.asset" as a single word with whitespace delimiting.  I use this sort of selection sometimes and it works well.

Comment: Thanks man! You saved me :3